# Azure B2C UI customisations <div id="api"></div>

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Has anyone got experience with Azure B2C UI customisations using this: 
 approach

I have the custom HTML in an Azure blob, cors enabled etc.

I want to embed the custom HTML into an existing page.

I can do with by calling the "Run now" endpoints, taking the responsibility and embedding the content on to my page but then the form doesn't work, it submits/calls out to my reply URL.

I've tried custom policies as well.
I've hit a wall with the whole thing.

I've read these [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) and  [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)

but I need more practical examples/help.
Email, Skype whatever.

Comment: Pls take a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question in SO. SO is not intended for getting practical examples

Comment: Please add to the question some code, to make easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Hi Tony. What I am looking for at the end of the day, is not be redirected to login.microsoft.com to sign or sign in but I cant figure it out. I am hoping this is more a configuration fix.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't "embed" the Azure AD B2C experience in your relying party application.

Instead, you can implement the sign up or sign in experience in your relying party application and then integrate it with Azure AD B2C using [the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to create a local account and [a resource owner policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) to validate credentials for a local account.

Otherwise, you can [use the `{tenant}.b2clogin.com` domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin), rather than the `login.microsoftonline.com` one, for your Azure AD B2C service if you are wanting to remove references to Microsoft from your sign-up and sign-in flows.

Comment: Thanks Chris. So there no way in configuration to rename/mask login.microsoftonline.com to something else, a custom domain?

Comment: Hi @PhilipDuggan Yes, I've updated the above answer, with information about using the b2clogin domain.